# Print related data only in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I am looking for an input to print related fields only in bibliography and not also in cites. I am using `philosophy-verbose`.

Usually, I use related fields for reprints, or translation. Here is an example:

```
@article{crisafulli1948,
    author={Crisafulli, Vezio},
    title={Sull'efficacia normativa delle disposizioni di principio della Costituzione},
    journal={Annali Triestini},
    note={sez.~\textsc{i}},
    issuetitle={Scritti in memoria di Luigi Cosattini},
    volume={18},
    year={1948},
    pages={21--42},
    related={crisafulli1952},
    relatedstring={rist.\ in}
}

@book{crisafulli1952,
    author={Crisafulli, Vezio},
    title={La Costituzione e le sue disposizioni di principio},
    xdata={giuffre},
    year={1952}
}
```

I have got footnotes, with full cites at the first time; and finally a bibliography. If I give in the text `\cite{crisafulli1948}`, I'll have in my footnote something like:

> V. Crisafulli, *Sull’efficacia normativa delle disposizioni di principio della Costituzione*, in «Annali Triestini», vol. XVIII, 1948: *Scritti in memoria di Luigi Cosattini*, sez. I, pp. 21-42, rist. in *La Costituzione e le sue disposizioni di principio*, Giuffrè, Milano 1952.

Same kind of output in bibliography.

But I am looking for a shorter footnote, like as:

> V. Crisafulli, *Sull’efficacia normativa delle disposizioni di principio della Costituzione*, in «Annali Triestini», vol. XVIII, 1948: *Scritti in memoria di Luigi Cosattini*, sez. I, pp. 21-42.

I'd like to have the related fields in bibliography. This is the reason because I can not use `related=false` in the preamble of `biblatex`.

I highlight that I should need of an input good for every kind of entries and not only for articles. So, I can not change `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}`. It would be strenuous to change every `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{*}`.

Of course, If you have got a solution good not only for `philosophy-verbose`, but also for other similar styles, I would be more pleased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the toggle `bbx:related` that controls whether or not the related data is printed to false in all citations with `\AtEveryCitekey`.

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=philosophy-verbose]{biblatex}

\AtEveryCitekey{\togglefalse{bbx:related}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{crisafulli1948,
  author        = {Crisafulli, Vezio},
  title         = {Sull'efficacia normativa delle disposizioni di principio della Costituzione},
  journal       = {Annali Triestini},
  note          = {sez.~\textsc{i}},
  issuetitle    = {Scritti in memoria di Luigi Cosattini},
  volume        = {18},
  year          = {1948},
  pages         = {21--42},
  related       = {crisafulli1952},
  relatedstring = {rist.\ in},
}
@book{crisafulli1952,
  author    = {Crisafulli, Vezio},
  title     = {La Costituzione e le sue disposizioni di principio},
  publisher = {Giuffrè},
  location  = {Milano},
  year      = {1952},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{crisafulli1948}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Footnote citation

[image: Vezio Crisafulli, «Sull’efficacia normativa delle disposizioni di principio della Costituzione», Annali Triestini, 18 (1948): Scritti in memoria di Luigi Cosattini, sez. i, p. 21-42.]

bibliography

[image: Crisafulli, Vezio, «Sull’efficacia normativa delle disposizioni di principio della Costituzione», Annali Triestini, 18 (1948): Scritti in memoria di Luigi Cosattini, sez. i, p. 21-42, rist. in La Costituzione e le sue disposizioni di principio, Giuffrè, Milano 1952.]

Comment: It works, thanks! How simple it was...